# Reduce doxygen PDF index depth + remove extra indices

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen

Is it possible to reduce the depth of the index created by doxygen for a latex PDF?

E.G. Currently doxygen creates an index in the PDF that is 4 levels deep: file name - documentation type - documentation items.
I'd like to reduce this to just 1 level - the file names and then possibly also get rid of the data structure index (chapter 2) and the file index (chapter 3)

Couldnt see anything for this in header.tex etc.

Nearly sure I saw a similar Q on here a few weeks ago but I couldn't find it

(NOTE this is all relevant to the *PDF* produced, Im not using the HTML output)

Comment: When not mistaken in the header.tex file it is: \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}.

Comment: @albert Thanks, that works a treat! Do you know how I can get rid of the data structure and file indices altogether as well?

Comment: Oop, found this in the doxy config file - "LATEX_HIDE_INDICES" - needed to be set to YES

Comment: @albert if you want to make our comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @albert commented it is controlled by the line \setcounter{tocdepth}{n} in the header.tex file.

Where n is a number indicating the number of levels required.